# JOIN Query for Specific Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have the following tables:

### Login

IDUser (Int) 
username (Var) 
pass (Var)

### Photos

IdPhoto (Int)
title (Var)
IdUser (Int)

### Following

IdUser (Int)
followingID (Int)

**I am trying to create a query that fetches the 'photos' from the people you are following.**

So far, I have created a query that grabs the 'photos' from everyone across the service:

```
$query = "SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN following login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE following.followingID = following.userID ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does the followingID link to the the Photos IdUser of the person you are following?

Comment: huh @Fred i dont know what u mean

Comment: Is followingID holding the IDUser that is found in the photos and login table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*, l.IdUser, l.username 
FROM following f 
LEFT JOIN login l ON f.followingID = l.IDUser 
LEFT JOIN photos p ON p.IdUser = l.IdUser 
WHERE f.idUser = 1 
LIMIT 50
```

This should fetch photos of people followed by user id = 1 in this example.

Comment: f.IdUser is the field in your table called following, isn't it what you described?

Comment: Yes but this doesn't work. Is f.IdUser the ID of the user I am following or myself?

Comment: It might not work if you wrote some column names here wrong, you can take a look at an error, or more accurately describe your db.

Comment: That's exactly what my DB is like. They're all seperate tables with information. What's SELECT p.*, do?

Comment: I assume that f.IdUser is your ID and the followingID is the id's of people you follow. I don't know it is your design.

Comment: SELECT p.* selects all fields from photos table because in JOIN statement it is mentioned that p is alias (2nd name) for table photos. it is the same as to write photos.*

Comment: I've recreated your DB on my local and there was an I missing in JOIN, so try this new query.

Comment: How would i do it so that it's for all of the people a specific user is following?

Comment: WHERE f.idUser = 1  <--- here put the ID of a specific user instead of 1

Comment: It obviously depends on what programming language are you using if at all to figure out how to put that number inside the query.

Comment: is f.idUser the id for the user I'm following or the user that I am

Comment: of the user that you are.